# how to use the script tag element in react js , where I am using the react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Usage of smart payment buttons by PayPal:

how to use the smart payment button in Paypal ? when I am rendering the button I am getting errors , this is the script which I want to use here :

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

I am using the useEffect to load the script :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=API_KEY&currency=USD";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, []);
```

after that , I am rendering the summary of the registration in card where I want to render this Paypal smart button

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
            .....
            //registration details
            .....
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions style={{justifyContent:"center"}} >
            {renderPaypal}
         // renderPaypal invokes the function to render the button
        </CardActions>

    </Card>
```

Here this is the function where I render the button :

```
   const renderPaypal=()=>{
    return (
        <script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                return data.orderID;
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

)
}
```

Comment: Can you also include which errors are you getting. This could help other users to find the problem faster.